# Mimic the 'pause' function in debug using diagnostics

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, response, diagnostics

I have a site that, too often, takes a *long* time to respond. I have no idea why, and checking the code and running this on dev and staging servers only gets us so far. When I'm debugging, I have the ability to pause the process so I can see what method it's currently working in. Can I somehow mimic this using diagnostics on a live environment?

To be clear, is there some way to write out a diagnostics trace only if the site is taking longer than X amount of seconds to respond with the method it's currently processing? Or is there a more appropriate way of logging method times instead of inserting calls to a diagnostics method hundreds of times in the existing code?

**What I've Tried**

I've tried using a decent profiler, but it can only profile sites on the current environment. I cannot profile my live site remotely.

Comment: If you are using Azure, that allows for remote debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a tool to obtain a process dump which you can then analyse.

For .NET/IIS applications I usually use [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) to obtain the dump, and the analysis tool in [Debug Diag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40336) to analyse it.

If you've never done this kind of thing before, then you will probably need a [walkthrough](https://www.leansentry.com/Guide/IIS-AspNet-Hangs) to help you out.

If you're lucky enough to be using Azure, you can [remotely debug your web sites and cloud services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/05/remote-debugging-a-window-azure-web-site-with-visual-studio-2013.aspx), which is more straightforward.